Isolate elements by workset in Revit
Is there a tool in Revit that allows to temporary isolate elements by a workset?
For example - I have a MEP project and I want to isolate in 3D view all elements which are on Plumbing workset.
By now I found one way of doing it with DiRoots plug-in but it involves a lot of steps and I'm searching for an easier way. Couldn't find such functionality in pyRevit. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

we have a script that creates a 3D view for each workset. Essentially it loops through worksets, creates a 3D view, turns all worksets off, then shows the current workset.
For your situation, try this code with your 3D view open:
worksetNameToShow = "Plumbing"
view = ui.ActiveView
worksets = list(FilteredWorksetCollector(doc).OfKind(WorksetKind.UserWorkset))
    
for workset in worksets:
    if workset.Name == worksetNameToShow:
        view.SetWorksetVisibility (workset.Id, WorksetVisibility.Visible)
    else:
        view.SetWorksetVisibility (workset.Id, WorksetVisibility.Hidden)

